# Room does not insert data to table

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

It is interesting point that it sometimes performs insert operation correctly. I do not know why and how this situation can be happens. So, I could not figure out where I made a mistake(s). 
Here is my project files.

1) SentFilesDao.java

```
@Dao
public interface SentFilesDao {
    @Query("SELECT id, name, type, status, dateTime FROM sent")
    LiveData<List<SentFilesEntity>> getAllSentFiles();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insert(SentFilesEntity file);

    @Query("DELETE FROM sent")
    void deleteAllRecords();
}
```

2) SentFilesRepository.java

```
public class SentFilesRepository {
    private SentFilesDao mSentFilesDao;
    private LiveData<List<SentFilesEntity>> mAllSentFiles;

    SentFilesRepository(Application application) {
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mSentFilesDao = db.mSentFilesDao();
        mAllSentFiles = mSentFilesDao.getAllSentFiles();
    }

    LiveData<List<SentFilesEntity>> getAllSentFiles() { return mAllSentFiles; }

    public void insert(SentFilesEntity sentFilesEntity) {
        new SentFilesRepository.insertAsyncTask(mSentFilesDao).execute(sentFilesEntity);
    }

    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<SentFilesEntity, Void, Void> {
        private SentFilesDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        insertAsyncTask(SentFilesDao dao) {
            mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final SentFilesEntity... params) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
            Log.e("doInBackground: ", "reached here!"); // no any log in Logcat about this. Weird...
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

3) SentFilesEntity.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "sent")
public class SentFilesEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    public int s_f_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String s_f_name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    public String s_f_type;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    public String s_f_operation_status;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dateTime")
    public String s_f_time;
}
```

4) SentFilesViewModel.java

```
public class SentFilesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private SentFilesRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<SentFilesEntity>> mAllSentFiles;

    public SentFilesViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new SentFilesRepository(application);
        mAllSentFiles = mRepository.getAllSentFiles();
    }

    public LiveData<List<SentFilesEntity>> getAllSentFiles() { return mAllSentFiles; }

    public void insert(SentFilesEntity sentFile) { mRepository.insert(sentFile); }
}
```

**What I am trying to do:**

My program sends selected files from one device to another one through WiFi Direct. As file received or sent, I want to save some information about file (such as file name, file type (image, video, music, APK and etc.), send/receive date and time) and operation (succeeded or failed). I can handle all these things.

**What is the problem?**

Well, getting all the properties (those I mentioned above), is not *end*. Main problem is saving that data to database. To do that I created some required files (I shared their codes above). When file sent, I am trying to insert related information to database. But it does not insert it. That is the my problem.

Well, main codes are too long to post here. However I posted my latest codes to my GitHub project and the main logic [starts from here](https://github.com/mirjalal/MickiNet/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/talmir/mickinet/activities/HomeActivity.java#L248) and it connected to `FileStatisticsActivity`.

p.s: Maybe sharing the project link is not *ethic*, I am so sorry for that.

Thanks.

Comment: "Room does not insert data to table" -- how have you determined this?

Comment: By examining the database file.

Comment: That did not provide much information for the people who might try to help you. For example, you have `OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE`, so you are intentionally saying that you want "Room does not insert data to table" when there is an existing primary key match. We do not know the details of what you are inserting or the details of how you are "examining the database file". All I can suggest is that you consider [writing some tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests) and using them to help identify the source of your difficulty.

Comment: thanks, @CommonsWare for the comment. I edited my question so, added some details about my problem.